# Client get new data from server

Tags: json, http, client, client-server, server

I am designing a web app where the server generates batches of data, and the client periodically checks whether new batches of data are available for download. The way I am doing this is that whenever the server generates a new batch of data, it is available at a particular URL. The client periodically checks the URL to see whether a new batch is available for it. (I am currently not using web sockets.) This batch of data is in the format of a JSON object.

Since I have very little web experience, I'm a bit confused about what to do when the client visits the URL. How should the client know whether the batches of data at the URL are new (in which case the client should download them) or old (in which case the client should ignore them, since it has already downloaded them in the past)?

Also, there may be multiple clients working with the same server, so the solution should work regardless of the number of clients.

Comment: Upon further research, I think that I might have to use the "HTTP Error 304 - Not modified", in which case the client should ignore the batches of data on the webpage, since the client has already downloaded those batches. However, assuming that the webpage has been updated since the last time the client visited, how should the client know which batches of data on the webpage are new (that it should download) and which are old (that it should ignore, since it has already downloaded them)?

Answer (score 1):

Include the Timestamp property (through server side script) in the JSON which is thrown by the server. You need to change the value of timestamp property everytime you update data to your server. Now it would be easy for you to detect change by checking the modification date.

Comment: Thanks. If I timestamp each data batch (because only batches with later timestamps are useful to me) is there a way to only download those batches with the later timestamp? Or do I need to download all the batches to the client? The data is in JSON, and I'm using Javascript with AJAX on the client side, if that helps.

Comment: Can not you have only a single batch and keep updating itself rather than having more batches